# Having trouble writing parsed strings to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, date, file-io

I have a CSV file that contains "dirty" data and my goal is to clean it up by rewriting it to a new file called [inputFile]_fixed.csv. The part that I'm having trouble with is only certain cells are being reformatted, while the rest are being rewritten. I know the code is parsing the input correctly, because I'm writing the new strings to the console, but it's not translating to the CSV for some reason.

You will notice that only the last three dates were output to the new CSV, and all three were originally formatted with the months in either `MMM` or `MMMM`. You will also notice that the code worked when outputting just to the console.

Code portion:

```cs
string[] fields = {};
while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
{
    fields = csvParser.ReadFields()!;
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputDirectory, true))
    {  
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", FixData(fields)));
    }
}

static string[] FixData(string[] fields)
{
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        cellData = fields[i];
        if (cellData.Contains("/") || cellData.Contains("-") || cellData.Contains("\\"))
            {
                if(!cellData.Contains("."))
                {
                    if (!cellData.StartsWith("-") && !cellData.EndsWith("-"))
                    {
                        cellData = cellData.Replace("\\", "/");
                        DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(cellData, culture);
                        newDateString = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        Console.WriteLine(newDateString);
                        fields[i] = newDateString;                    
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

Input CSV (I replaced irrelevant cells with `...`):

```
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2016/04/14,2016/04/14,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2015-04-13,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2014\04\12,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2-16-2016,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2\15\2015,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2/14/2014,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,2016-04-04,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,12-Aug-2015,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,13-January-2011,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,13-february-2011,...,...,...,...
```

Output CSV (I replaced irrelevant cells with `...`):

```
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2016/04/14,2016/04/14,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2015-04-13,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2014/04/12,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2-16-2016,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2/15/2015,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2/14/2014,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2016-04-04,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2015-08-12,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2011-01-13,...,...,...,...
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...,...,2011-02-13,...,...,...,...
```

Console Output:

```
2016-04-14
2016-04-14
2015-04-13
2014-04-12
2016-02-16
2015-02-15
2014-02-14
2016-04-04
2015-08-12
2011-01-13
2011-02-13
```

Comment: FixData is not returning anything. Please add the code.

Comment: @PalleDue Whoops - added now.

Comment: I tried to reproduce, but I cannot get `Datetime.Parse` to recognize the backslash as a valid date delimiter. Do you do some other fixing?

Comment: @PalleDue Yes sorry I should have mentioned that. I use `cellData.Replace("\\", "/");` to replace the backslashes with forward slashes right before `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: There are still inconsistencies in the example code. You need give more realistic code. Obviously the bug is in the parts you omitted.

Comment: @BoppityBop I've edited the sample code to be more realistic.